# Bloclistener Causing ambiguity in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, state, bloc

I have 9 screens where I am using fields to fill form from user inputs. I am using bloc for state management. The problem is with the navigation. I am using navigation with bloc listener. When i move from screen 1 to 2 and move back everything is ok.
from screen 2 to 3 and back everything is ok.
from screen 3 to 4 Navigation is ok but when I click for back many navigation screens pop up like screen 2 two times when i press back button 2 times then screen 3 pop up and then screen 1 pop up with back button.
and this behavior continue so forth until I reached last screen and remove all previous screens. my app also become very slow when i navigate with bloc listener. I dont know what is this behaviour.

Screen 1 bloc.

```
BlocListener<JobBloc, JobState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is JobSuccessfulState)
          widget.edit == true
              ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        JobPostScreen8(state.data),
                  ),
                  (route) =>
                      false, //if you want to disable back feature set to false
                )
              : Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => JobPostScreen2()));
      },
```

Screen 2

```
BlocListener<JobBloc, JobState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is JobSuccessfulState)
          widget.edit == true
              ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        JobPostScreen8(state.data),
                  ),
                  (route) =>
                      false, //if you want to disable back feature set to false
                )
              : Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => JobPostScreen3()));
      },
```

Screen 3

```
BlocListener<JobBloc, JobState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is JobSuccessfulState)
          widget.edit == true
              ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        JobPostScreen8(state.data),
                  ),
                  (route) =>
                      false, //if you want to disable back feature set to false
                )
              : Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => JobPostScreen4()));
      },
```

...
and it is all same upto screen 7. Screen 7

```
BlocListener<JobBloc, JobState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is JobSuccessfulState)
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => JobPostScreen8(state.data),
            ),
                (route) =>
            false, //if you want to disable back feature set to false
          );
      },
```

with this all navigation stack is removed and my application run smoothly. Please suggest me what is better approch in navigation with bloc.